# Managing Git branches and subbranches?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I am trying to figure out how to manage Git branches so I have a correct and readable flow for my development process.

Basically, we have a master branch, a project branch, then we can start to develop features under this project branch. I would like to be able to make subbranches too.

Say I would have master - > project -> feature 1 -> feature 1 sub 1 ...

What I would get in Hg would look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAz5c.png]

What I actually get under git is this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6mmx.png]

Basically, the whole development flow is lost, and in 1 year there will be no way to know that "Interface refactoring" was related and a sub part of "Duplication of speed model".

Moreover, I am avoiding fast forward merges because it just lost track of all history, but still, in a few months even I won't be able to tell that "Update necessary setExecutionMode" was done under "InterfaceRefactoring" and not "Duplication of ..."

I am seriously considering going back to Hg and using a plugin to make a bridge between Hg and Git, because Git is so incredibly NOT user friendly, but I also badly want to use the company tool as it is still a modern and efficient SCM (not like SVN or CVS).

I still think that I could get what I want, I just don't understand how.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would advise actually looking at your Git Network Graph for a more accurate look at what the branch structure looks like.

Comment: In git, a branch is simply a pointer to a commit. It holds no history information. I'm curious how you avoid fast-forward merges. Do you do extra commits to ensure a merge occurs?

Comment: What is a git network graph ?

Comment: Wolf: there's a tortoiseGit merge option: No Fast Forward (command line: --no-ff).

it forces a merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't have what Mercurial calls "named branches."  Instead, what Git calls "branches" are very similar to what Mercurial calls [bookmarks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Bookmarks).  There are a few differences:

- In Git, every head must have a branch pointer or it is considered semi-nonexistent (a "detached HEAD") and may be garbage collected after a while.  Such heads will not appear in the repository history, but can be retrieved from the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).  This contrasts with Mercurial, where bookmarks are entirely optional.
- Git maintains "remote branches" all the time, while Mercurial only does this when the local and remote bookmarks diverge (you get a "divergent bookmarks" warning and a bookmark with a name like `foo@default` is added to the repository).  This means that Git's local branches must be manually fast-forwarded after a pull, while Mercurial fast-forwards local bookmarks automatically on pull.
- In Mercurial, `@` is a special bookmark which may or may not exist.  If it does, cloning checks it out by default.  It can be used as a pointer to the trunk (default branch), though that is not its only use.  In Git, `@` is shorthand for the current commit, and the "main" branch is instead called `master`.

If you need Mercurial-like branches, you should use Mercurial instead of Git.

Comment: Thanks.
Please not that if I could use Mercurial, I definitely would :)

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial branches are strings attached to commits. Git commits do not have such dedicated strings, but you could put a keyword to the subject:

- EDF merge speed duplication
- DSPEED stuff
- REFACTOR_INTERFACE stuff

Some put there a number from bugtracker

Comment: In general, feature requests and bugs ought to appear in the bug tracker anyway, so putting a bug number in most commit messages is good practice regardless of Git vs. Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Also, since you anyway use the non-fastforward merges, it is possible to request which commits have contributed to the merge with command

```
git log *mergehash*~1..*mergehash*
```

this range query also can be various UIs, for example gitk (in view definition) and GitExtentions (in branch selector)